# Good hash function to remove duplicates from array

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Can any one suggest good has-function to remove duplicates from the array in order to use moderate memory consumption? Remember I am using hash map solution for that but want good hash function. Otherwise the memory consumption depends on the biggest element of the array.

Its an array of integers....

Comment: C or C++? It surely makes a difference. What implementation of a hash table do you use?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without any information about the keys of the hash. Strings, integers?

Comment: what types do you have in the array and what is the range of values?

Comment: What kind of integers are they? What is their range? Could you tell anything else about them?

Comment: Are the numbers randomly distributed, i.e. is every number in the array about equally likely to appear? If so, you can just use modulo.

Comment: Do you use hash chaining or open hashing for the hash table (reference here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing). are the number values evenly sparsed in the domain of values?

Comment: The thing is that there will be no need for chaining or any other stuff in my required function. If there is any collision then i will simple ignore that variable but my concern is the size of the hash function. if the integer has its own hashing then the size of hash table will depend only on the biggest element in the array. and if the elements in the array are {1,2,2,3,5,1,9,6,25635}. then my hash function will be of size 25635 and a lot of memory will be wasted...

Comment: @AbdulSamad: you are mistaken about something. A hash function goal is to map an input to an integer within a specified range. However the hash itself is not use *raw*, instead it is used as a hint by the hash table, which will be sized only depending on its number of elements.

Answer (score 4):

Your question lack details, so I'll just make them up.

Hashing an integer is usually useless. An integer is its own hash.

What matters most is the size of the integer (how many bits), the number of different elements (so that we know how much the side table will grow) and the number of elements in the array (to estimate how much operations it will take).

The simplest solution to eliminating duplicates is usually sort + unification. Or in Unix:

```
cat list | sort -u
```

In C++, this can be achieved through the `<algorithm>`:

```
std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end());
vector.erase(std::unique(vector.begin(), vector.end()), vector.end());
```

However this will obviously sort the array so may not be desirable. In this case, you can always use a side table.

- If the range of the integers is small (say all in `[0, 65536)` for example), then just use a regular table with the integers as indexes. Using a bitset you can easily get them.
- If the range grows, things depend more on how sparse the range is.

  - For a sparse range, indeed a hash table can be a good approach
  - However for a full range (eg, very few duplicates and large number of elements) then the hash table will grow enormously and might become too big, in this case perhaps than a Bloom Filter (ie probabilistic approach) would work better.

Answer (score 0):

There is very small point in hashing an integer since it is already small enough to do comparison. You can sort the array and remove subsequent elements that are equal easily. If you really want to hash them just take, for example, first two bytes into a short and it is your hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MAD (multiply add and divide) method, which helps eliminate repeated patterns in a set of integer keys.

h(k) = |ak + b| mod N,

where N is a prime number, and a and b are non-negative integers randomly chosen so that a mod N != 0. But you still need to deal with collisions.